# LaTeX Multiple Table Alignment Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align multiple table and tried in several different ways, unfortunately none of them works. Here i have attached a sample code for your perusal. Will you please suggest me how to get rid of this type of silly problems. I will really appreciate your sincere support. Thank You

The output can be found using this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t131bdd007z5g1/Test_Post.pdf?dl=0). 
[image: Sample Output]

**Sample code:-**

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red,  urlcolor=blue}
    \usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.65in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx,xcolor,colortbl}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mdwlist}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
    \usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
    \usepackage{lastpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage
    \pagestyle{fancy}% Set default page style to fancy
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
    \fancyhead{}% Remove all header contents
    \cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}% Page X of Y in the footer (centered)

    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

    \begin{document}


    \section{ABCdhahdak dahd }
    \hrule

    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabulary}{1.00\textwidth}{r|| L c}
    time &  ajdhahsdash dhas dhasjh dashd ashd ashdjah dhas dha & adlaksd \\
    adasd &  adlahf ahf ahfha dfhah fhad fha & \\
     &  sfhakd hfhadf ajdhf adhf adjfha fjdh fahf ahah fjadfh ajfhlad xfhalflgdh gjadf djhgad ghad gadjhg ad &  \\ 
     &  fa fjadh dfaf hajhf ahfah fhd fajhf adhf hajfh ahfjah fahf afh ajhf ahfjajhf h &  \\ 
     &  hhf ahfjh adhfaj fjahd fhaj fah jahf ahfjah fha fha &  \\
    \end{tabulary}

    \vspace{0.4cm}
    \hspace{-0cm}

    \vspace{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabulary}{1.00\textwidth}{r|| L c}
    time &  ajdhahsdash dhas dhasjh dashd ashd ashdjah dhas dha & adlaksd \\
    adasd &  adlahf ahf ahfha dfhah fhad fha & \\
     &  sfhakd hfhadf ajdhf adhf adjfha fjdh fahf ahah fjadfh ajfhlad xfhalflgdh gjadf djhgad ghad gadjhg ad &  \\ 
     &  fa fjadh dfaf hajhf ahfah fhd fajhf adhf hajfh ahfjah fahf afh ajhf ahfjajhf h &  \\ 
     &  hhf ahfjh adhfaj fjahd fhaj fah jahf ahfjah fha fha &  \\
    \end{tabulary}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\noindent` to start the table in the left margin.

I am not sure if you want align also the table columns. In this case, use the  `p{}` columns when needed, instead of `r`, `l` or `c` columns, where the width depend of the content:

```
 \noindent\begin{tabulary}{1.00\textwidth}{p{1.5cm}|| L c}
```