# Multiple Table Horizontal Alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, ieeetran

I am trying to put up multiple tables together. (Scroll down for MWE). I can not figure out why the last table is misaligned. I tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219386/latex-multiple-table-alignment-horizontally-and-vertically) but it did not work for me as I am not using the [`tabulary`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) package.

**PDF Output I am Getting:**
[image: PDF Output I am Getting]

**PDF Output Desired:**
[image: PDF Output Desired]

MWE :

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcolumntype{M}{R@{${}={}$}L}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}{
        \begin{tabular}{M|c}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rules (Continuous Case)}      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mbox{cv}_{w}$}      \\\hline
        V^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 4.459     & 0.24                            \\
        S^{1.000}x_{2}^{0.999} & 89.971      & 0.26                            \\
        x_{1}^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 0.500  & 0.54                             \\
        y^{1.000} & 2.001                    & 0.85                \\ \hline      
        \end{tabular}\hfill
        %
        \begin{tabular}{M|c}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rules (Continuous Case)}      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mbox{cv}_{w}$}      \\\hline
        V^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 4.459     & 0.24                            \\
        S^{1.000}x_{2}^{0.999} & 89.971      & 0.26                            \\
        x_{1}^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 0.500  & 0.54                             \\
        y^{1.000} & 2.001                     & 0.85           \\\hline               
        \end{tabular}\hfill
        %
        \begin{tabular}{M|c}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rules (Continuous Case)}      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mbox{cv}_{w}$}      \\\hline
        V^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 4.459     & 0.24                            \\
        S^{1.000}x_{2}^{0.999} & 89.971      & 0.26                            \\
        x_{1}^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 0.500  & 0.54                             \\
        y^{1.000} & 2.001                     & 0.85           \\\hline               
        \end{tabular}\hfill
        %
        \begin{tabular}{M|c}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rules (Continuous Case)}      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mbox{cv}_{w}$}      \\\hline
        V^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 4.459     & 0.24                            \\
        S^{1.000}x_{2}^{0.999} & 89.971      & 0.26                            \\
        x_{1}^{1.000}x_{2}^{-1.000} & 0.500  & 0.54                             \\
        y^{1.000} & 2.001                     & 0.85                \\\hline          
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You code looks right here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nksmt2dq5yjmjcz/Sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o_027.png?dl=0

Comment: I get the desired output when I compile your minimal example.

Comment: @Werner You are right. When I tried the MWE in a online Latex editor (Sharelatex), I also got the desired output. But My editor produces the wrong output. I am using TexStudio 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 14.04_64 bit. Can that make a difference? Or the way the build commands are compiled in it, can that make the difference?

Comment: @Sigur You are right. When I tried the MWE in a online Latex editor (Sharelatex), I also got the desired output. But My editor produces the wrong output. I am using TexStudio 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 14.04_64 bit. Can that make a difference? Or the way the build commands are compiled in it, can that make the difference?

Comment: @Abhinav: Yes; Ubuntu is known for its outdated TeX distribution. Perhaps try something in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) and see if it rectifies your problem.

Comment: @Abhinav, just press F6 and then F7. What happens?

Comment: @Sigur Ya, the same thing still. :(

Comment: I get the desired output on my system as well (up-to-date TL 2014). Potentially stupid question: is there a reason you need to stack `tabular`s this way? Why not code it so each "column" is one `tabular`?

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes, as each table is for a different data set. I have shown otherwise for my ease. I wish to use Subcaptioned tables but that requires `subcaption.sty` (by Axel Sommerfeldt) which changes the captioning style in IEEEtran.cls and I dont know a work around. So in a way, I am stuffing what is supposed to go into subcaption of each subtable into column name. Hope this helps. I'll check it on some Windows machine tomorrow which has an up-to-date TeX distribution. May be it will go as others are reporting. Just dont want to risk updating my TeX distribution right now, short on time.

Comment: @Abhinav OK, that does make sense. Thanks for clarifying. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem appears to be caused by outdated packages.